# Save files to extension storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm new to browser extension development. I'm trying to make a webextension for Chrome, Firefox and other browsers which allows users to select a file (images, mp4 etc.) from their computer and later set that on the new tab page.

My problem is that I couldn't find any way to let users select a file from their computers and later access it in the extension scope. I've figured out changing new tab page setting (at least for Chrome, seems Firefox doesn't allow this yet).

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1084992

Comment: Simply save as a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) in any storage you like e.g. chrome.storage.local.